# NVD3.js Get Data Point's Screen Position Within SVG Chart

Tags: charts, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm using the nvd3.js [line with focus chart ( view finder )](http://nvd3.org/ghpages/lineWithFocus.html) model for a project. There are customizations that i need to add to this example -- such as different types of annotation overlays on top of the graph.

[image: spec]

There's a couple ways i can see tackling this:

**1.** I could extend the nvd3 chart models to create one that does what i need ( that seems like a lot of work at the moment )

**2.** I can find the right interfaces in the existing nvd3 chart models and write my own d3 stuff to create annotations ( this seemed easier, and so i went down this route )

I've figured out most of what i need except how to get the chart's svg screen position for a value from my xScale ( d3.linear.scale() ). Once i have the correct screen position within the nvd3 chart i can make my annotation overlay in the correct spots.

**Question:**
Does anyone know if there's an interface in nvd3 charts to calculate the chart's screen position from an xScale value? If there's no easy interface, how could i solve this problem?

Thanks

**UPDATE:** It looks like i had all the correct information to begin with thanks to Lars' comment. But it wasn't making sense since there seems to be a bug when setting xAxis with dates like this:

```
 chart.xAxis
  .tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%d')(new Date(d)); });
```

When you try to get the xAxis.scale(), you get a date back instead of the scale function. So it wasn't obvious.

Comment: You should be able to access the scale through `xAxis.scale()`.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: yep, you are right. Though a subtle bug in nvd3.js seems to have kept that conclusion from me for some time. See my update above

Comment: Yeah, NVD3 does some attribute wrapping of its own that can be confusing at times. I'll add that as an answer anyway for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to access the scale through `xAxis.scale()`. You should run this code after the graph has been drawn to make sure that the scale is set up properly.

Answer (score 0):

To add some context to the solution by Lars:

My xAxis is setup like:

```
chart.xAxis
  .tickValues([
    Date.parse('08/24/14'),
    Date.parse('08/30/14'),
    // parsed dates..
  ])
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d))
  });
```

Then, after the chart has been rendered (in the callback), I can then get the x position for a certain date value by doing:

`chart.xScale()(chart.x()({ x: Date.parse('11/01/14') }))`

Hope this helps someone. Cheers.