# How to add annotations to a nvd3 chart?

Tags: charts, nvd3.js

I need to add annotations to a nvd3 line chart. I want to display a placeholder with some text at some data points in the graph. I guess I need to find the correct coordinates on the chart and add a div with the information to the graph but I don't know how to do that. Any ideas?

Comment: May be related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389295/nvd3-js-get-data-points-screen-position-within-svg-chart