# Is it possible to draw custom markers with nvd3?

Tags: angular, d3.js, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

I am trying to choose the best technology for plotting a rich graph which should contain a mix with few charts types like Line Chart, Scatter Chart, Bar Chart, Candlestick and other inside one canvas.
Currently I'm looking at Angular 2 NVD3 labrary (ng2-nvd3) and my testing purpose is to plot the similar graph:

[image]

My question is: is it possible with NVD3? Can I place custom images (markers) on the plot? If it possible could you provide a link with example?

Comment: It seems like you're basically trying to add annotations to the chart. This stack overflow thread might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389295/nvd3-js-get-data-points-screen-position-within-svg-chart

Comment: Thank you jeznag. I decided to learn a "plain" D3 to understand the basics